# tf.data.Dataset.list_files how to iter over a tensor with @tf.function decorator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, python-decorators, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to use as much as possible the tf API (tf version 2.x) in my jupyter notebook even for the regular string handling ops.

Specifically I'm getting the list of files in a folder through the method tf.data.Dataset.list_files

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

extension = '*.png'
myFolder = 'myFolder'
pathFiles = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(os.path.join(myFolder,extension))
```

Now pathFiles is a <TensorSliceDataset shapes: (), types: tf.string>

and type(pathFiles) returns tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TensorSliceDataset.

I can access the first element in this way in order to do all my operations:

```
element = next(iter(pathFiles))
element.numpy().decode("utf-8")
...
```

I do the same operation over the whole Tensor through a for loop.
I.e.

```
for i in pathFiles:
    i.numpy().decode("utf-8")
    print(i,type(i))
    ...
```

or:

```
for i in iter(pathFiles):
    i.numpy().decode("utf-8")
    print(i,type(i))
    ...
```

However as soon as I define a function and then decorate with @tf.function.
I get wired stuff that I cannot handle as without the decorator.
Specifically:

```
@tf.function
def f(path):
    print(path)
    print(type(path))
    for i in path:
        print(i)
        print(type(i))
    for i in iter(path):
        print(i)
        print(type(i))

f(pathFiles)
```

<_VariantDataset shapes: (), types: tf.string>

<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._VariantDataset'>

Tensor("args_1:0", shape=(), dtype=string)

<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>

Tensor("OptionalGetValue:0", shape=(), dtype=string)

<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>

Comment: I've understood that even though I'm using tf.data.Dataset which are executed in Eager mode the script works when I set

`tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)`

Comment: What do you want to do with your code ? Do you need to extract the path of the image in string to be able to load it afterward ?

Comment: @Thlang that's correct

Comment: Ok, and why do you want to make your function a tf.function ?